# Index out of range error in c# and IsLetter() also selecting space instead of Only alphabets

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the plain text: ");
string ptxt=Console.ReadLine();
ptxt= ptxt.ToUpper();
char[] ptxtarr = ptxt.ToCharArray();
for(i=0; i<=ptxt.Length;i++)         
    {           
        if(char.IsLetter(ptxtarr[i]))
        {
            nptxtarr.Add(ptxtarr[j]);
            j++;
        }              
    }
```

getting error at `ptxtarr[i]` for the last value of the array for string "hello world"
also char.Isletter() should select only alphabets but it also selects space, why so?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZzvL.png)

Comment: `< ptxt.Length`, not `<=`. `arr[arr.Length]` is already past the end. Also `char.IsLetter()` will not match a space, however note that it will match any Unicode character classified as a letter, including cyrillic and arabic for instance.

Comment: What is 'j' variable, is it declared?

Comment: i was actually doing something more inside the loop and hence needed the j , but removed that but forgot to replace the j with i damm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points.

- Arrays in `C#` follows zero based index.
- `j<=ptxt.Length`causes your inner statement to look for n+1 element in n `length` array.

Multiple ways we can fix this problem.

```
for(i=0; i<ptxt.Length;i++)         
{           
     if(char.IsLetter(ptxtarr[i]))
     {
         // logic here
     }
}
```

**or**

```
foreach (char c in ptxtarr)
{
    if(char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Alternateively, we can also use `Linq`.

```
if(ptxtarr.All(char.IsLetter)) // Verifies every character is a letter.
{
     // logic here.
     nptxtarr = ptxtarr
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone, got it solved
correcting the j with i and changing for condition <= to < did it.

coded after a long time, i made some silly mistakes...
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `j` in the if clause?
it should be like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the plain text: ");
string ptxt=Console.ReadLine();
ptxt= ptxt.ToUpper();
char[] ptxtarr = ptxt.ToCharArray();
for(i=0; i<=ptxt.Length;i++)         
{

    if(char.IsLetter(ptxtarr[i]))
    {
        nptxtarr.Add(ptxtarr[i]);
    } 

}
```

it is troublesome using that `j` variable as it will add those space and you get string with less character as the space count
for example you have string `'hello world'` using your code it will return `'hello worl'` The reason is when your code encountered space, it will not increment the `j` and therefore the added char is the space which is next char after your last added char

Comment: Correct and concise. I propose a different method to accomplish the same result in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `char[]` Follows Zero based indexing. that means if the array having three elements the indices will be `0`,`1`,`2`. and the length of the array will be `3` which denotes the number of elements in the array.

What you have to do to solve your problem is :

1. Change your Looping condition as like this:

   ```
    for(i=0; i<ptxt.Length;i++) 
    {
      //Do your stuff here  
    }
   ```
2. Use foreach instead for this:

   ```
    foreach (char c in ptxtarr)
       {
          if(char.IsLetter(c))
            {
              nptxtarr.Add(c);
            }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Oh please stop this nonsense.

The reason it appears that Char.IsLetter() thinks that spaces are characters is that you're index is not your incrementor. You increment `i` in your for loop declaration, but you're using a separate letter, `j`, when you select from your character array. Since you only increment j when you hit a letter, but `i` increments on its own, your loop will correctly skip the space, but then still include it in your result array since `j` has not been incremented.

For future reference, include all relevant code. We're clearly missing the declarations for `j` and `nptxtarr`.

This will accomplish what you're looking to do without the unsightly loops or bugs:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the plain text: ");

char[] letters = Console.ReadLine()
    .ToUpper()
    .Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c))
    .ToArray();
```

That will produce an array of upper case letters from one line of user input. What you do with it is up to you.

**Why this works:**

string is a series of unicode characters (look at the tooltip). It's enumerable and supports the `IEnumerable` interface. This takes the input from the console, converts it to upper case, enumerates through the characters that make up the string which qualify as Char.IsLetter and spits out an array of those characters.